# Why does locking an std::mutex prevent timer callbacks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, callback, mutex

I am writing an audio engine and use `timeSetEvent` to call the engine's update function on about every 20 ms. In the main thread I call a method of another class that locks an `std::mutex` object. As soon as the mutex is locked, the timer callback is no longer executed.

Is `timeSetEvent` not compatible with mutexes or could there be any other reason?

Comment: For others - Windows [`timeSetEvent` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Is your event handling involving the same `mutex`?  If so, are you sure you're unlocking it at the end of the event?  You're not accidentally trying to use it recursively anywhere?

Comment: My fault. When adding the mutex I accidently uncommented a return statement so `unlock` would actually never be reached. Thanks.